# Querying for a substring within a field in elasticsearch

Tags: java, rest, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I'm trying to query all documents in an index that have 143=NEWYORK in the msg field. Here's an example:

```
"_index": "sample-2018.07.23",
"_type": "logs",
"_id": "osDryGQBWeBeIkHntjFo",
"_score": 11.664754,
"_source": {
"msg":"u00011=hi\u00013=i'm\u00028=trying\u0001=to\u000169=query\u000143=NEWYORK,
"symbol": "FB",
"side": "1",
"receivingsession": "SIMQA", ....
```

This document has "msg:"u00011=hi........u143=NEWYORK" which I'd want returned.

The queries I've tried have included:

1. {"query":{"bool":{"should":[{"query_string":{"query":"143=NEWYORK"}}]}}}
2. {"query":{"bool":{"should":[{"match":{"msg":"143=Newyork"}}}]}}}

and neither of these work. For some reason if I try only "Newyork" as opposed to "143=NewYork" it works fine. Does anyone have a solution, any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add your mapping?

Answer (score 0):

How about using `query_string` instead:

```
    {"query": { "bool" : "must" : [{ "query_string" : {"query" : "msg" : "*143=Newyork*" }}]}
```

Comment: Are you getting an errors?  How are the values indexed?

Comment: Looks like youre going through Kibana.  Is that correct?

Comment: Not really sure if we're using kibana, it's indexed based on DEV,QA,UAT. I'm not getting errors but rather all instances where 143 shows up.